# How to convert webelement to string in selenium using java? Please refers to detail section for more info

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I created a `POM` for 'Create project' page

```
public static class addProjInfo_container
        {
            public static WebElement ProjName_txt(WebDriver driver)
            {
                element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Project Name']/following-sibling::input"));

                return element;
            }
// and so on for every text field for adding project...
```

And I created a `TestUtility` class with method for `waitForElement` as show below

```
public final class TestUtility {

    private static WebDriver driver;


    public static void waitforElementXpath(final WebDriver driver,final int waitTime,final String xp)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait =new WebDriverWait(driver, waitTime);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xp)));
    }
}
```

Now, in Test script I want to avoid using `Thread.sleep()` to wait for webelement to be ready to start performing actions.

so, I use

```
TestUtility.waitforElementXpath(driver,10,CreateProject_Page.addProjInfo_container.projName_txt(driver));
```

But,it displays error as

```
The method waitforElementXpath(WebDriver, int, String) in the type TestUtility is not applicable for the arguments (WebDriver, int, WebElement)
```

Kindly, let me know how to handle the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your want to reverse the By to get its string and you are using xpath

so change to this  which return the String instead of WebElement

```
  public static class addProjInfo_container {
    public static String projName_txt(WebDriver driver) {
        By by = By.xpath("//label[text()='Project Name']/following-sibling::input");
        driver.findElement(by);
        return getSelectorAsString(by);

    }

    public static String getSelectorAsString(By by) {
        String str = by.toString();
        return str.substring(str.indexOf(" ") , str.length());
      }
    // and so on for every text field for adding project...
}
```

hope this could help

Comment: In case you want a more generic approach  so that you can do the wait with xpath or id or name or tagName or cssSelector; please let me know  Alan Mehio, London

Answer (score 0):

This is really a convoluted way of trying to accomplish this task. Your `ProjName_txt()` method already has found the element because that's what it returns so you don't need to wait for it to appear by using `waitforElementXpath()`. I would recommend that you read some articles on OOP and classes before you write too much more code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is:

```
String name = driver.findElementByClassName("classnamesample").getText() ;
```

Just add `.getText()` in the last of xpath and receive this as `String`.

Answer (score 0):

The below given answer is useful.

```
String expectedSearchText = drivers.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[contains(text(),'latest')]")).getText();
```